# Can we use the delta-ep def of a limit to find a limiting value?

Tags: calculus, limits, epsilon-delta

I had a random thought recently that we don't really use the delta epsilon definition for evaluating limiting values. So, I decided to have a crack at it just now. Could somebody check whether my reasoning is sound or if I've just assumed some nonsense somewhere?

**Example**
Using only the definition of a limit, evaluate
$$\lim_{x\to0}x=L$$
for some limiting value L. It does not matter whether L exists or not.

$Solution.$ Let us consider the function $f:(-a,a)\to\mathbb{R}$ for $f(x)=x$. As per our definition for a limit, there exist a $L$ such that for every $\varepsilon>0$ there exists a $\delta>0$ such that for all $x\in(-a,a)$
$$0<|x|<\delta\ \implies\ |x-L|<\varepsilon.$$
Rewriting our first inequality using the triangle inequality give us
$$|x|=|(x-L)+L|\geq||x-L|-|L||.$$
Rearranging $0<|x-L|-|L|<\delta$ gives us
$$-\delta<|x-L|-|L|<0 \quad \text{or} \quad 0<|x-L|-|L|<\delta.$$
It follows that
$$|L|-\delta<|x-L|<|L| \quad \text{or} \quad |L|<|x-L|<|L|+\delta$$
As such, we know
$$|x-L|<|L|\ \text{or}\ |x-L|>|L|\ \implies\ |x-L|\neq|L|$$
This means either: (1) $x$ is not $0$ and/or $x$ is not $2L$, or (2) $L=0$.

However, the former is contradiction since $0<|x|<\delta$ implies $|x-L|<\varepsilon$, which would need to hold for $x=0$ since $0\in(-a,a)$. Therefore $L=0$ if $L$ exists.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your posts (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: You fail to even specify the question?  What limit?  Your title tells us nothing with respect to the limit about which you are concerned.

Comment: Sorry I'm new to MSE. I just typed up my working and removed the picture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> As per our definition for a limit, there exist a $L$ such that for every $\varepsilon>0$ ... .

I hope what you intended to say was

> As per our definition for a limit, **if $f$ has a limit at $0$ then** there exist a $L$ such that for every $\varepsilon>0$ ... .

Also ask yourself this: at what point in this proof did you invoke the specific properties of $f$? I have another function $g$ defined on $(-a,a)$ by
$$ g(x) = \begin{cases} 1/x & x \neq 0, \\ 0 & x = 0. \end{cases} $$

Does this proof work equally well if we change the definition of $f$ to the definition of $g$? Yes, it does, because no part of the definition of $f$ was ever invoked. Yet obviously $g$ does not have a limit at $0$, so there must be something wrong with the proof.

Other than the missing words right at the beginning, the reasoning seems good to me up to and including this part:

> This means either: (1) $x$ is not $0$ and/or $x$ is not $2L$, or (2) $L=0$.

But notice that if $L\neq 0$ then (1) is satisfied for every $x$ due to the "and/or":
if $L\neq 0$ and $x = 0$ then (1) is satisfied due to satisfying "$x$ is not $0$",
whereas if $L\neq 0$ and $x \neq 0$ then (1) is satisfied due to satisfying "$x$ is not $2L$".

Comment: So the main problem seems to be that function itself is not referred to when I'm manipulating the inequalities to produce some L. I had hoped looking at the domain would be sufficient. Is there a legal way to do this or is this just a lost cause?

Comment: Also it seems if I just specified the domains this approach would work, but all the working would be pretty much useless.

Comment: I assume that the purpose of this exercise was to find the limiting value $L$, whereas the usual way to use epsilon-delta requires that you know (or guess) the correct value of $L$ first. It's an intriguing idea, but the hope that it could be made to work seems too good to be true--it seems it would solve unsolvable problems.